# \flushmaketitle not defined

Tags: moderncv

I'm really sorry to ask this question but I find myself unable to answer it for myself, with little idea of what went wrong:

I created a template for my CV using LaTeX, which worked fine for a year, but I let it untouched for 2 months. I had to recently upgrade my linux distribution and lost a number of libraries in the process (I mention it without a clue whether it's relevant or not). The end of the story is that now, I can't compile my `.tex` code.

Among various warnings, I see the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: \flushmaketitle undefined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.24
> ```
>
> \renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}

Another maybe relevant warning is

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadiii', but the package provides`moderncvheadiii'.
>
> LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii', but the package provides`moderncvbodyiii'.

Here is a cleared version of the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
    \moderncvstyle{banking}
    \moderncvcolor{black}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hscale=0.8, vscale=1, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}  %% Option 'sfdefault' only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.}       
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0., 0.6, 0.8}  

            \makeatletter
                \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

                \renewcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
                  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
                  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
                  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
                  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}

                \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
                  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.7\textwidth}
                  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{
                    \raggedright

                    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}\\
                    \vspace{0.2cm}
                    \addressfont\color{color2}%
                    \vspace{0.1cm}
                    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}
                     %
                     \flushmaketitle 
                     \@firstmaketitleelementtrue}
                     }
                     %}
                    \addtomaketitle{\emaillink{\@email}}

                    \collectionloop{phones}{\addtomaketitle{\@mobile}}
                    \vspace{0.1cm}

                    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
                    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@title}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@title}}%
                    %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@fax}}%
                                    \vspace{0.1cm}
                    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}

                \newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
                    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
                    {\color{#1}%
                        \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
                }

            %   \patchcmd{\maketitle}{\\[2.5em]}{\hfill\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\cfbox{color1}{\includegraphics[width=80pt]{/home/pierre/Documents/Personnel/CVFR/moi1}}}\\[2.5em]}
            \makeatother

\firstname{Pierre}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Street}{Lane}
\mobile{+60669412}
\email{pierre.doe@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{age\hspace{7pt}} 
\title{\hspace{1pt}} 
\fax{} 

\begin{document}  
    \makecvtitle
\nopagenumbers{}

% this puts a dashed thing on the header
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \fill[pattern=dots, pattern color=color1, overlay] (-0.2,0.2) rectangle (17,4.4);
%   \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1cm,delta angle=180, overlay]
    \node[circle,draw=color1,inner sep=1.3cm,fill overzoom image=/home/pierre/Documents/.jpg] (A) at (15cm,2.8cm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{0pt}\section{Formation}\vspace{4pt}
    \cventry{something}{something}{}{}{}{}\vspace{-12pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At a guess, in upgrading linux you've updated moderncv and some of the internals of the moderncv package have changed.  Possibly adding `\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{}` near the beginning will make the document compile though it will probably not look as you want it.  The "You requested package..." warnings will not cause errors or stop compiling and so can be left.  What I expect you want to know (outside my knowledge) is what the `\flushmaketitle` command has been renamed to in the moderncv package.

Comment: Do you have an old `log` file (I mean from the time you can compile the cv)? If yes please check in that `log` file which (old) version of `moderncv` you have used.  In the current version 2 the command is not defined.  Can you explain  in short words, what that command should do?

Comment: The `moderncv` class underwent substantial refactoring when stepping the main version number to 2. Unfortunately, there's no hint in the documentation about what happened to `\flushmaketitle`

Answer (score 4):

Well, in the new version 2.0 of `moderncv` there was a renaming from old version `flushmaketitle` to  `flushmakeheaddetails`.

That means you can try to change the error causing command `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand` (because the following command has to be defined new now) like

```
% <=====================================================================
\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%  new version 2.0 flushmaketitle -> flushmakeheaddetails
```

That compiles for me, but I do not know what you expect and it could be there are other errors now.  Please check that with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hscale=0.8, vscale=1, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}  %% Option 'sfdefault' only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.}       
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0., 0.6, 0.8}  

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% <=====================================================================
\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%  new version 2.0 flushmaketitle -> flushmakeheaddetails
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}%
}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.7\textwidth}
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{
    \raggedright

  \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}\\
  \vspace{0.2cm}
  \addressfont\color{color2}%
  \vspace{0.1cm}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{%
    \addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}
    %
    \flushmaketitle 
    \@firstmaketitleelementtrue}
  }
                     %}
                    \addtomaketitle{\emaillink{\@email}}

                    \collectionloop{phones}{\addtomaketitle{\@mobile}}
                    \vspace{0.1cm}

                    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
                    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@title}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@title}}%
                    %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@fax}}%
                                    \vspace{0.1cm}
                    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}

\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  {\color{#1}%
  \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}

%\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\\[2.5em]}{\hfill\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\cfbox{color1}{\includegraphics[width=80pt]{/home/pierre/Documents/Personnel/CVFR/moi1}}}\\[2.5em]}
\makeatother

\firstname{Pierre}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Street}{Lane}
\mobile{+60669412}
\email{pierre.doe@gmail.com}
\extrainfo{age\hspace{7pt}} 
\title{\hspace{1pt}} 
\fax{} 


\begin{document}  
\makecvtitle
\nopagenumbers{}

% this puts a dashed thing on the header
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \fill[pattern=dots, pattern color=color1, overlay] (-0.2,0.2) rectangle (17,4.4);
%   \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1cm,delta angle=180, overlay]
    \node[circle,draw=color1,inner sep=1.3cm,fill overzoom image=example-image-a.jpg] (A) at (15cm,2.8cm) {}; % image=/home/pierre/Documents/.jpg
    \end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{0pt}\section{Formation}\vspace{4pt}
    \cventry{something}{something}{}{}{}{}\vspace{-12pt}

\end{document}
```

I changed the image file name too and get then the result:

[image]

Is that close to that what you need?  If not the only chance is to install the old version of `moderncv` or change your code to be able to use verion 2.0 (that would be better in my eyes ...)

Comment: thank you again! However this is not exactly what I had: the name is in the middle (I put it flushed left for balance, iirc I had a casual header and a banking body). Also, the orders of the fields have changed (for instance the field on the right of the vertical bar is now my nationality). And finally and that's what I'm trying to figure atm, is how to get rid of icons. Using \moderncvicons{} instead of \moderncvicons{awesome} does not work...

Comment: I did not unfortunately. However I reinstalled the 1.5.1 version and can provide you with a visual:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdc62dy34oexp8o/CV_test.pdf?dl=0